# Jquery function only works on the first row even with $(document).on()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, invoice

I followed a tutorial for invoice system using PHP jquery mysql and bootstrap. I followed the codes character by character but the $(document).on() function for a certain class do not work. On the tutorials video however, it seemed to be working. **The main problem is the $(document).on() function call only works for the first row in the table, and NOT for the rest of the rows.**

*Thank you for your help in advance...*

HTML part:

```
<td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_quantity"></td>

<td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price'+id+'" data-srno="'+id+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_price"></td>

<td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>
```

Jquery function:

```
             var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
             var total = $('#total_item').val();
             var count = 1;
                    function cal_final_total(count){
                        var final_item_total = 0;
                        for(var j=1; j<=total; j++){
                            var qty = 0;
                            var price = 0;
                            var actual_amount = 0;

                            qty = $('#order_item_quantity'+j).val();

                            if (qty > 0) {
                            price = $('#order_item_price'+j).val();
                               if (price > 0) {
                                   actual_amount = parseFloat(qty)*parseFloat(price);
                                   $('#order_item_actual_amount'+j).val(actual_amount);
                               }
                            }
```

$(document).on() function call

```
                    $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_price', function(){
                        cal_final_total(count);
                    });
```

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but I did check similar questions here and try the suggested solutions but none of them seem to work. Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: As you’ve presented it here, it will only work when you move out of the *second column*, which is the only one with class `order_item_price`

Comment: because I omitted some parts of the entire code.. But thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just replace this code to resolve it

```
function cal_final_total() {
    var final_item_total = 0;
    $('.order_item_quantity').each(function(){
        parent = $(this).closest('tr');
        qty = +parent.find('.order_item_quantity').val();
        price = +parent.find('.order_item_price').val();
        actualAmount = qty*price;
        final_item_total += final_item_total;
        parent.find('.order_item_actual_amount').val(actualAmount);
    });
}
```

make sure your input field are in separate **tr** tag